# Power Analysis in [R] for Two-Way Anova

Tags: r, analysis, anova

I am trying to calculate the necessary sample size for a 2x2 factorial design. I have two questions.

1) I am using the package pwr and the one way anova function to calculate the necessary sample size using the following code

```
pwr.anova.test(k = , n = , f = , sig.level = , power = )
```

However, I would like to look at two way anova, since this is more efficient at estimating group means than one way anova.  There is no two-way anova function that I could find.  Is there a package or routine in [R] to do this?

2) Moreover, am I safe in assuming that since I am using a one-way anova power calculations, that the sample size will be more conservative (i.e. larger)?

Comment: This is not programming related, but you should go vote for Rob Hyndman's site proposal here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/proposal-for-statistics-data-mining-stackexchange-site.

Answer (score 2):

In a 2 x 2 ANOVA involving Factor A, Factor B, and AxB, you will get separate statistical power estimates for each of these three effects.

G Power 3 provides free software and some clear tutorials for estimating power of effects in factorial designs:
http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/abteilungen/aap/gpower3/user-guide-by-design

Comment: "Separate" for balanced designs :)

Answer (score 0):

After searching - I couldn't find any solution for this online.

What I would suggest you to do (if you know how) is to program this using a simulation.
If you don't know how to do it, then write a SO question about "How can I write a simulation of two-way anova, to achieve power analysis" and see what people might help you with :)

Also, you could start by reviewing the code here:

http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/NCStats/power.sim.html

For a start on power calculation through simulation.

Notice what Jeromy wrote - this power analysis is for multiple outcomes.

Interesting subject - I'd love to followup on it.

Best,

Tal

Comment: Thanks you two for the input Jeremy and Tal. I will think about your suggestions and how to incorporate them.

Comment: @Thomas Have you opened another post for your question ? You just need one line in R to compute power of a F-test. Not a good place but here is a function which does the job: `Power <- function(alpha, eff, n, m, l) {
    df1 <- m - l
    df2 <- n - m
    c <- qf(1 - alpha, df1, df2)
    lambda <- eff^2 * n
    pow <- pf(c, df1, df2, ncp = lambda, lower.tail = FALSE)
    return(pow)
}`